# How do you call a method of a class in a certain level of the hierarchy, not the lowest one?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, hierarchy

Say that I have:

```
class Foo
{
    string name1;
    public Foo(string name1)
    {
        this.name1 = name1;
        something();
    }
    virtual void something()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name1);
    }
}

class Bar inherits Foo
{
    public Bar(string name1, string name2) : base(name1)
    {
        this.name2 = name2;
        something();
    } 

    override void something()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good bye, " + name2);
    }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is that the `something()` on the `Foo` constructor calls the `something` defined by `Foo`, not the one defined by `Bar`.
But if I do this:

```
Bar b = new Bar("A", "B");
```

the `Bar` constructor invokes the `Foo` constructor which calls the `something` defined by Bar, not by Foo.

I know that what I want to do is a bad object oriented design. I'm doing it for the sake of optimization.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: you can try overload instead of override

Comment: You are missing the [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9fkccyh4.aspx) keyword.

Comment: This leads to a bad OOP design.  If you intend to call something on the base object - make it apparent.  You don't want to mix your implementations between the base and child classes.  As another posted - the base.Something() is the best way to ensure this is being called from the correct location.

Comment: “I'm doing it for the sake of optimization.” What kind of optimization? Could you explain it to us? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: @svick, sure. I'm doing a compiler for a course I'm taking. By "optimization" I'm referring to doing the least possible number of passes to the parse tree. "something" actually stands for a pass that I'm trying to do at the same time I'm parsing, therefore, I'm calling something at the constructors of the constructions. I believe that a good OOP design would advise against calling methods not required for initialization at initialization.

Comment: @LayGonzález So why is the code in a normal method? Why not put it directly into the constructor?

Comment: @svick I was about to say: "because the "something" method may be reused later". But I will actually have to double check that.

Comment: @LayGonzález If that's the only reason (*method may be reused later*) you should go with the second solution from my answer: separated private method called from both `something` and `constructor`.

Comment: @svick,MarcinJuraszek. I tried to keep my question as generic as possible so that others may benefit from it, but I also appreciate your advises about my design. I will rethink my design.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Why should I go with the second option?

Comment: Because it does not change the polymorphism flow between different `something` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `something` method within `Bar` with `new` keyword:

```
new void something()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good bye, " + name2);
}
```

With this, every `something` call from within `Foo` class will call `Foo.something`. And you're not able to call `Bar.something` from there.

With that, you can call `Foo.something` by just casting your `Bar` object to `Foo`:

```
((Foo)barInstance).something() // calls Foo.something()
barInstance.something() // calls Bar.something()
```

Another way to do that and keep the polymorphism: call different method from your `Foo` constructor.

```
class Foo
{
    string name1;
    public Foo(string name1)
    {
        this.name1 = name1;
        somethingImpl();
    }
    virtual void something()
    {
       somethingImpl();
    }
    private void somethingImpl()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name1);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this (your first option) defeats the purpose of having `Foo.something` `virtual`. Also, I think using a different name for `Bar.something` would be clearer than `new`.

Comment: @svick Yes, I agree. I've added that as another way of solving the problem.

Comment: About the second option, wouldn't I have the same problem? Bar would call Foo, which would call Bar's somethingImpl()? Never mind, thats the purpose of making it private... I see.

Comment: `Bar` constructor would call `Foo` constructor (by `:base()`), which would call `somethingImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `base.something()` from your `Bar` class

```
public class Foo
    {
        string name1;
        public Foo(string name1)
        {
            this.name1 = name1;
        }

        public virtual void something()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name1);
        }
    }

    public class Bar : Foo
    {
        private string name2;

        public Bar(string name1, string name2)
            : base(name1)
        {
            this.name2 = name2;
            something();
        }

        public override void something()
        {
            base.something();
            Console.WriteLine("Good bye, " + name2);
        }
    }
```

The output is name1= A and name2= B would be:
"Hello, A"
"Good bye, B"

Comment: But if I create a Foo, something won't be called.

Comment: Then write Foo as an abstract class and use two derived classes for your implementations. This way you can eliminate this logic dependency on your base class.